# Getting all points of a given connected component rapidly

Tags: python, blob, scikit-image, connected-components

Scikit-Image has quite a few methods available for blob detection:

Laplacian of Gaussian (LoG)

Difference of Gaussian (DoG)

Determinant of Hessian (DoH)

All three return an array that contains a single point within the bounds of the found components:

```
>>> from skimage import data, feature
>>> img = data.coins()
>>> feature.blob_doh(img)
array([[ 121.        ,  271.        ,   30.        ],
       [ 123.        ,   44.        ,   23.55555556],
       [ 123.        ,  205.        ,   20.33333333],
       [ 124.        ,  336.        ,   20.33333333],
       [ 126.        ,  101.        ,   20.33333333],
       [ 126.        ,  153.        ,   20.33333333],
       [ 156.        ,  302.        ,   30.        ],
       [ 185.        ,  348.        ,   30.        ],
       [ 192.        ,  212.        ,   23.55555556],
       [ 193.        ,  275.        ,   23.55555556],
       [ 195.        ,  100.        ,   23.55555556],
       [ 197.        ,   44.        ,   20.33333333],
       [ 197.        ,  153.        ,   20.33333333],
       [ 260.        ,  173.        ,   30.        ],
       [ 262.        ,  243.        ,   23.55555556],
       [ 265.        ,  113.        ,   23.55555556],
       [ 270.        ,  363.        ,   30.        ]])
```

I'd like to use that information to produce lists that contains the coordinates of all the points in a given component.

I could just iterate through the whole image myself starting with the seeds and just collect all the points in a dict with the key being the point provide by blob detection, but I imagine it would rather slow unless I'm using cython(more than willing to be wrong about this, as I'm fairly new to python). More truthfully, I simply think there is probably a better way then just doing it myself.

Comment: The blob detectors return a centroid and a radius (or some related quantity), so you can easily iterate over the centres and compute all coordinates contained within (one vectorized operation per centroid).  It should not be too slow, if you have a reasonable number of centroids.

Comment: Whoa a response from @StefanvanderWalt! I didn't realize from the documentation that the third category was the radius, I just assumed it was some confidence quantity(which sounds silly now that i type it out). Thanks